# Net use admin$ on remote not in my workgroup

Tags: windows, network-share, service, net

I have a remote server where I want to acquire admin access by opening the admin share with:

```
net use \\123.123.123.123\admin$ password /user:username
```

This is in order to issue the following command later:

```
sc \\123.123.123.123 query tomcat7-8888
```

After a while of waiting for `net use` to finish, I get system error 53 network-path not found. I then googled and found the group policy setting:

> Network Security: Restrict NTLM: Outgoing NTLM traffic to remote servers

might help.

It didn't make a difference though.

Any idea how to make it work? 
Is it even advisable to open a box up like this in terms of security?

Comment: The most likely cause is the firewall configuration on the server.  You should probably undo whatever group policy changes you've made on the client.

Answer (score 4):

Kerberos is not used when you connect to SMB shares by using IP address and if a client tries to connect to e.g. a share by its IP address it would fall back to NTLM.

NT Lan Manager (NTLM) is a proprietary Microsoft security protocol for providing authentication in the Windows operating system. NTLM has a number of known vulnerabilities, including that it uses weaker cryptography and has no server authentication.

The workaround/solution:

1. Allow NTLM with GPO or local policy. Or add exceptions like in this [guide](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/network-security-restrict-ntlm-add-remote-server-exceptions-for-ntlm-authentication).
2. Use FQDN/PQDN for connection instead of IPs

Comment: Do you have some reason to think that the OPs problem is related to NTLM?  Since the request is timing out, it seems more likely that the remote machine is firewalled.